# Boot Mint21 with display turned off

Tags: boot, display

Since upgrading from Mint 20 to Mint 21, my Shuttle DH310 mini PC doesn't boot properly if it doesn't have a monitor attached (and turned on). Sometimes I don't need the display because I just want to connect to the Shuttle via SSH to do something at the command line level.

Worse than that, my brother has a similar set-up with two mini PCs connected to one HDMI splitter with a "toggle" button that controls which machine's output is sent to his TV. If the toggle isn't connecting the right PC, it won't boot.

Below is what I hope is the relevant "System Information" from my Shuttle DH310. Is there anything easy I can do to force correct video output *before* connecting/turning on the display?

---

Machine:
Type: Desktop System: Shuttle product: DH310 v: 1.0 serial: 
Mobo: Shuttle model: FS310 v: 1.0 serial:  UEFI: American Megatrends
v: 1.11 date: 02/08/2021
CPU:
Info: 6-core model: Intel Core i5-8400 bits: 64 type: MCP arch: Coffee Lake rev: A cache:
L1: 384 KiB L2: 1.5 MiB L3: 9 MiB
Speed (MHz): avg: 3856 high: 3899 min/max: 800/4000 cores: 1: 3799 2: 3892 3: 3899 4: 3899
5: 3852 6: 3798 bogomips: 33599
Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
Device-1: Intel CoffeeLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
vendor: Holco Enterprise Co /Shuttle CometLake-S driver: i915 v: kernel ports: active: DP-2
empty: DP-1,DP-3,HDMI-A-1 bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:3e92
Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa
gpu: i915 display-ID: :0 screens: 1
Screen-1: 0 s-res: 3840x2160 s-dpi: 96
Monitor-1: DP-2 model: HISENSE res: 3840x2160 dpi: 140 diag: 1321mm (52")
OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 22.2.5 direct render: Yes